# How many primitive operations are in this statement?

Tags: java, algorithm, primitive

```
S = (S / (N * N)) * 100.0
```

Primitive operation: Basic computations performed by an algorithm in pseudocode.

For the code above I got a count of 6 operations. I have detailed this below.

- 1 operation for the write to "S"
- 1 operation for the read of "S"
- 1 operation for the "/"
- 1 operation for the read of the first "N"
- 1 operation for the first "*"
- 0 operations for the second "N" because the computer would have already read the first "N" (not sure if this is correct).
- 1 operation for the last "*"

I am not sure if my count is correct. I would apprechite if someone could double check this. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a definition of what you consider "_a primitive operation_"?

Comment: Primitive operation: Basic computations performed by an algorithm

Comment: This is not a formal definition and does not explain what exactly is considered such an algorithm. "Basic computations" is vague and ambigious.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Has someone else asked you this in homework or an interview?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by primitive operation.

You said:

> *"because the computer would have already read the first "N" "*

That may or may not be true.  It depends on what the Java compilers do.  (The bytecode compiler AND the JIT compiler).  A Java compiler is *permitted* to either optimize this or not optimize it.

But here's the thing: if you are counting primitive operations so that you can perform a "first principle" complexity analysis, it won't matter if you count this statement as 5 or 6 primitive operations ... or even 1 primitive operation.  All of them will give the same answer: this statement is `O(1)`.

Comment: Also, during runtime, depends on the CPU. The CPU may or may not cache the variables.

Comment: And other things.  For example, some primitive operations take longer than others, and the order of instructions can affect execution time due to pipeline effects.